# How to run ef code first migrations in a appharbor sql database?

Tags: migration, ef-code-first, appharbor

I know that in heroku you can run

```
heroku rake db:migrate
```

from your ruby console and itll run the migrations on the database for your heroku app.

Is there something similar for appharbor and ef code first migrations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Entity Framework team is working on this and there's a beta out. Here's a blog post from [Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/EntityFrameworkCodeFirstMigrationsAlphaNuGetPackageOfTheWeek10.aspx). This feature comes with support for migrating to remote servers (like the one you might have on AppHarbor) too.